# v2 to v3 Google Maps wrapper API to test old application

Tags: google-maps

Let me first state that I have tried to get the answer to this question from my Google account representative.  After trying to get an answer for several weeks, he emailed me and told me to post this question here in this forum.  I give this explanation in the hopes my question doesn't get put on hold.

I have an old Google maps API v2 application.  We have been working on rewriting this in v3, and should be done before Google deprecates the v2 of maps on Nov 18th.

However, we saw this notice on Google's site:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/

On Nov 18, the v2 API goes away, and Google provides a v2 wrapper that is wrapped with the commands for v3 API, essentially converting v2 commands to v3.

I am wondering if we will be able to get access to the WRAPPED version of v3 that supports v2 commands BEFORE NOV 18th, so that I can verify that our old code will work with the wrapped version of the v3 API, just in case we don't have our new application done in time.

Comment: Your Google Account representative told you to post your question here , what does he do then to help you !

Answer (score 1):

We have quite a few sites using various map packages and like 09stephenb said we simply had to wait.

Things started playing up in all versions of IE and older versions of FireFox (12.0)

Firefox 25 and Chrome were handling the wrapped maps fine.

Just as we were planning a rewrite of all scripts this morning it seems Google have sorted out the wrapped version for the problematic ones mentioned before.

Just in case anyone here has missed this and is beginning to migrate.

Cheers.
Liam