# Can I use Google Maps v2 code with a new API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a new API key but all my code is for Google Maps v2. I'm aware there is an [upgrade guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3) but I don't want to change any code if possible. I had:

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=MY_OLD_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and now I have

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=MY_NEW_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- it doesn't seem to care about the v=2 -->
```

and as far as I can tell it works fine. There are no errors in the console. There's only a warning about Map.addControl no longer being supported and that's fine. I don't need that feature anyways.

But is it safe to just update the key like I did and walk away from this code? Unfortunately the version 2 documentation is nowhere to be found. The only thing I can find is Google telling me to upgrade to 3. But again, if all I have to do is change the key and it will work fine then I don't want to make any code changes.

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API v2 has been deprecated and turned off since May 19, 2010.  It has been replaced by a wrapper for the v3 version of the API, but the functionality of that wrapper has been slowly decaying.  If the v2 API works, that is all you can hope for, it is no longer supported by Google.

Comment: So google just turned off google maps for everyone using version 2? Wouldn't that break a lot of apps in production? The code I am working on does work. I just don't know if it's safe to swap out the API key.

Comment: They didn't "just turn it off", they replaced it with a wrapper for v3.  The documentation for v2 can be found on archive.org

Comment: So it is still "on" then? I'm just trying to figure out if it's safe to swap the keys as opposed to embarking on a days long porting process.

Comment: Define "safe".  Google deprecated it in 2010, they could turn it off at any time (given it will break any v2 maps that are out there)

Comment: It should show the users location and any pins that were put on the map.

Comment: Anyways, it does look like it will be safe because of the wrapper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191537/v2-to-v3-google-maps-wrapper-api-to-test-old-application unfortunately google has broken the links to information about the wrapper as well. But it sounds safe to me. That is, if it's been working these last few years it will probably continue to work.